# on first time page load Angular is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

on first load, angular is undefined, when i refresh the page second time it works fine, not sure it might be JS Lining,
pleas have a look : http://www.alhayygroup.com/#/

```
requirejs([
    "js/jquery-1.11.3.min",
    "js/angular.min",
    "js/bootstrap.min",
    "js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
    "js/angular-sanitize.min.js",
    "js/appSite.js",
    "js/angular-route.js",
    "js/appSiteCtrl.js",
    "js/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "js/angular-validate.js",
    "js/mobile_navigation.js"
    ], function(util) {
    //This function is called when all the js files is loaded.
    //If js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //js dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: load all angular related file before `js/appSite.js` like you need to move  `js/angular-route.js` & `js/angular-validate.js` move before `js/appSite.js`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because requirejs load js asynchronous ,if any of our `js` which is dependent on `angularjs.min` load before `angularjs.min` then you will get into this problem.